# Looking for something like exec() in vala

Tags: glib, vala

In vala, there is the command Process.spawn_command_line_sync().

But my problem is that I want to use libreoffice to convert an .odt file to .pdf. So i need all the programs in /usr/bin.

The command spawn_command_line_sync() does not provide this.

What is a good command to execute a shell script (system wide with all other executable binaries)?

Edit:

I need this:

Process.spawn_command_line_sync("libreoffice --convert-to pdf  " + temporary_dir + "file.odt");

But it can't find the command libreoffice, even it is installed. Other commmands like basic sh commands (rm, ls, dir, ...) do work.

Comment: What is wrong with `spawn_command_line_sync`, actually?

Comment: @user3840170: That it can't find the command 'libreoffice'. It looks like it only supports sh commands, but not system wide commands.

Comment: Works for me, just tried it. `spawn_command_line_sync` finds all commands in `/usr/bin`, in `/usr/local/bin`, and even in my custom `$HOME/.local/bin`, including `libreoffice`. (I would rather use `spawn_sync`, though, to avoid problems with file names containing spaces.)

Comment: I get this: Error: Failed to execute child process “libreoffice --convert-to pdf  /home/ubik/.myprogram/Temporary/writerdocument.odt” (No such file or directory). The file writerdocument.odt exists. Is this because I am using Gnome Builder? Other commands like rm, mv, etc. seem to work. I'm running Debian Stable.

Comment: @user3840170: How did you programmed the command? With Gnome Builder? When I try to list /usr/bin, i get this: Error: Failed to execute child process “ls /usr/bin/” (No such file or directory)

Comment: I need to ask the question in a different way: Where can I set PATH in Gnome Builder? Because 'ls /app/bin' works and 'ls /usr/bin' also works. ls '/lib' doesn't work.

Comment: Did you install Gnome Builder through Debian’s APT repositories or through some kind of container solution like xdg-app/Flatpak or Snap?

Comment: @user3840170: I installed through Debian's APT. Should I install through flatpak or snap? I've tried also to compile a single .vala file.

With this code it should also start libreoffice, but it doesn't: 

´using Posix;

static void main() {
  execl("libreoffice");

}´

Comment: No, just the opposite. I suspected the container may be interfering… though this may still be the case: look in the IDE’s options whether your project is built as a Flatpak package.

Comment: Okay, I tried again without Gnome Builder and it works. Where can I check whether my project is built as a Flatpak package? But I think, it is.

Comment: Solved: You have to configure Gnome Builder, that it will build a desktop app. As flatpak app it doesn't work.